# Incluir rutas css/js en los ficheros php en diferentes rutas de directorios y redireccionamiento

Tags: php, css, script, redirección, headers

hace tiempo que no programo en PHP y estoy montando una aplicación básica y me han surgido dudas:

Me estoy liando en como hacer para que me coja los estilos de css, la forma que había pensado es añadiendo la etiqueta  en un fichero header.php e incluirlo en todas las demás páginas .php sin tener que repetir código. 
Estructura de proyecto:

[image: Estructura de proyecto]

En mi index.php tengo: (Mas o menos)

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );
    include_once("header.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

En header.php tengo el head de html y he probado varias cosas como:

1:

```
<head>
    <title>titulo</title>
    <script src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>/assets/js/my-js-file.js"></script>
    <link href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>/assets/css/my-css-file.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

2: (he dejado dos aberturas de código php para que se vea mejor y se entienda pero en verdad esta con un echo)

```
<head>
    <title>titulo</title>
<?php
    echo '<script src='"'.ROOT_PATH.'"'/assets/js/my-js-file.js'"'></script>';
?>
<?php
    echo '<link href='"'.ROOT_PATH.'"'/assets/css/my-css-file.css'"' rel='"'stylesheet'"'>';
?>
</head>
```

he puesto "echo" para ver el valor de ROOT_PATH y la ruta que me muestra es correcta por lo que debería sustituirse bien pero algo no esta haciendo bien porque no se cargan los estilos en la web.

Me surgio este problema porque en en header.php yo tenía rutas absolutas:

```
<script src="./assets/js/my-js-file.js"></script>
```

Que cuando en index.php realizo el include ("header.php"); funciona correctamente pero si abro el fichero PROYECTO/modules/admin/index.php y incluyo también el header las rutas no están correctamente ya que intenta acceder a:
PROYECTO/modules/admin/assets/js/my-file-js.js y esto no es correcto.

¿Como se resolvería este problema o que otra forma puedo implementar para realizar esta tarea?

PD: ya se que al incluir el header.php antes de la etiqueta  esta mal por eso también me gustaría tener otras opciones de hacerlo.

Gracias.
EDITADO: he quitado la 2 duda que tenia con respecto a la buena conducta de formular preguntas, gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Hola. Creo que debes dividir tu pregunta. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a limitar mi respuesta a tu primera duda para seguir las normas de la comunidad.

La estructura de tus archivos está mal. Si vas a usar un fichero para el `header`, debería quedar algo así para abrir la estructura `html`:

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <!-- Enlazas tus hojas de estilos CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./ruta/css/tus_estilos.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- Puedes enlazar tu javascript aquí -->
        <script src="./ruta/js/tu_js.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
```

En los demás ficheros, haces el `include` de **header.php** y **footer.php**:

```
<?php
  include "./ruta/header.php";
?>
    <!-- Aquí pones todo tu código html, por ejemplo: -->
    <div>
      <p>El texto que debe aparecer en pantalla</p>
    </div>
<?php
  include "./ruta/footer.php";
?>
```

Y este sería el contenido de **footer.php** para cerrar la estructura `html`:

```
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Pero esto resolvería el tema de las rutas? Me refiero, teniendo el código como tu indicas, si lo incluyo en master-modules-profile-index.php (este index hago los include de header y footer), cuando vaya a ejecutar las rutas para buscar los css en ./ruta/css/tus_estilos.css? lo que yo quiero es que la "ruta" de los estilos sea dinámica o absoluta, para que lo llames de donde lo llames lo encuentre.

Comment: @abeld89 tu estructura de archivos esta mal, el sistema debe saber donde están tu archivo `head.php` y `footer.php` y esto debe ser estático y nunca cambiar, cualquier ruta que utilice debe armar tu html teniendo en cuenta eso... y el contenido que es la parte dinámica tambien debe estar parametrizada con la ruta... a esto se le llama Builder.